# picture upload does't upload picture anymore due to jquery plugin

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using Jquery mobile and I have a form that contain a file upload meant to upload a profile picture to be saved in a folder and database as well.It worked well when i had jquery 1.8.2 min.js plugged in but it messed my listview search but when i changed the jquery 1.8.2 to 1.5.2 it fixed the listview search but now doesn't allow me to upload picture when i click it doesn't open the directory.at the moment i removed the jquery 1.8.2 so i can't upload pictures.Can someone suggest what i can use to fix it.Is there another plugin that i can use to fix it or can i do it manually inside the file to fix it.I know the problem has to do with the plugins but which one can fix it.

```
My plugins

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

My Jquery codes

<div data-role="page" id="page5" >
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Vacancies</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
    <h5><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
        <?php  echo 'Welcome '.$_SESSION['username'];

        echo "<br><a href='logout.php' data-ajax='false'>Logout</a>"; ?> ...</h5> 

    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"  data-filter="true" id="jobList">
    <li data-role="list-divider"></li>

    </ul>
    <script>
    addToHomescreen();
    </script>
    </div>   
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>&copy;2016 &bull; Genesis M&C Holdings Pty</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

 $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080//recruitment//jobdetails.json", function(jobs){
   //Start off with an empty list every time to get the latest from server
   $('#jobList').empty();

   //add the job items as list
   $.each(jobs, function(i, job){
     $('#jobList').append(generateJobLink(job));
   });

   //refresh the list view to show the latest changes
  $('#jobList').listview().listview('refresh');    

 });

  //creates a job link list item
 function generateJobLink(job){

  //debugger;
  return '<li><a href="javascript:void(0)'
         + '" onclick="goToJobDetailPage(\''
         + job.jobtype 
         + '\',\''
         + job.city 
         + '\',\''
          + job.message 
         + '\',\''
          + job.details 
         + '\',\''
          + job.jobid 
         + '\',\''


         + job.jobid +'\')">' 
         + job.jobtype+"<h3></h3>"
          + job.city +"<p><strong><br>"
           + job.message +"<h4></h4>"

         + '</a></li>';
  }

  function goToJobDetailPage(jobType,jobCity,jobMessage,jobDetails,jobId){

   //create the page html template
   var jobPage = $("<div data-role='page' data-url=dummyUrl> <div data-role='header'><h1>"
                   + 'Job Details' + "</h1></div><div data-role='content'><strong><form style='border:dotted 1px #CCC' action='jobapp.php' method='post' data-ajax='false'>" 
                   + jobType + "</strong><h6> <input type='hidden' name='jobid'  value='"+ jobId +"' />"
                    + jobId + "</strong><h6> <input type='hidden' name='jobtype'  value='"+ jobType +"' />"
                   + jobCity +"</h6><p> <input type='hidden' name='city'  value='"+ jobCity +"' />"  
                   + jobDetails +"</P><input type='hidden' name='jobid'  value='"+ jobId +"' /><input type='hidden' name='jobtype'  value='"+ jobType +"' /><input type='hidden' name='city'  value='"+ jobCity +"' /> <div class='col-lg-10 text-center'><button type='submit' class='btn btn-warning' id='appbtn' name='appbtn' value='jobapp' data-role='none'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-envelope'></span>&nbsp;Apply</button><span>&nbsp</span><button type='submit' class='btn btn-danger' id='favbtn' name='favbtn' value='favorite' data-role='none'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-star'></span>&nbsp;Favorite</button></div></form></div><div data-role='footer'><h4>" 
                   + '&copy;2016 &bull; Genesis M&C Holdings Pty' + "</h4></div></div>");

   //append the new page to the page container
   jobPage.appendTo( $.mobile.pageContainer );

  //go to the newly created page
  $.mobile.changePage( jobPage );
  }  

</script>
```

Comment: check the browsers console, and report back the errors you see

Comment: this is what i got from checking the browser console"jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js:11 Uncaught cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'"

Comment: any reason why you are using such an old version of JQM??. anyway as i remember a few years back to get around that problem you do it 2ice. something like $( ".selector" ).listview().listview( "refresh" ); -- or $( ".selector" ).listview( "refresh" );.listview( "refresh" );  -- one of them should work

Comment: I am kind of old school.lol just kidding. the reason is when i use the newest JQM everything works but it messes up the design on the app basically it destroy the footer and i end up having some white spaces at the bottom of the page.Thanks for your answer, will try it and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks Tasos the trick works but now it broke my listview none of the elements on the list redirect to the appropriate page.

Comment: that must be some other problem so add the code in your Q to look

Comment: @Tasos ok i just inserted the codes in.Thanks again for all the trouble.hopefully we can work it out whenever i fix something the other trips.

Comment: try -- appendTo("body"); -- instead of -- appendTo( $.mobile.pageContainer )   --  and see if that helps -- also open the browsers console and check for any errors -- you also gave 2 versions of jquery loaded, you may get conflicts if used on the same document.

Comment: check here also for a solution with JQM 1.4 page issue you had --  https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/02/06/content-div-height-fill-page-height/ --- https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/05/15/content-div-height-fill-page-heightpart-2/